# Extracting arrays from a pgfmathdeclarefunction

Tags: tikz-pgf

So if I have

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{yeet}{...}{
\begingroup
\def\temp{#1}
\pgfmathsmuggle\temp
\endgroup
}
```

How can I save \temp to a new variable/array. In {1,2,3} format? If I use pgfmathparse
then it just converts the array into a string of numbers. However, this the only way I know of running the function "yeet". Even if I found some way of converting #1 back into {1,2,3} format I still wouldn't be able to extract it withought using pgfmathparse thus turning it back into 123

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep arrays "intact" by pretending they are strings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{yeet}{...}{\begingroup
\edef\pgfmathresult{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{yeet("{1,2,3}")}\pgfmathresult
\typeout{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{yeet("{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}")}\pgfmathresult
\typeout{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{yeet({1,2,3})}\pgfmathresult
\typeout{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{yeet({{1,2,3},{4,5,6}})}\pgfmathresult
\typeout{\pgfmathresult}

\end{document}
```

The output on the console is

```
1,2,3
{1,2,3},{4,5,6}
{{1}{2}{3}}
{{{1}{2}{3}}{{4}{5}{6}}}
```

As you see, without the `"` the arrays get "converted" to something that can be an argument of an ordinary macro. Why? Because this way you can convert a function of several arguments `f(x,y,...)` to something TeX can digest. It is clearly described in the pgfmanual v3.1.5 on p. 1047

[image]

Chances are, though, that you are not looking for a function declared with pgf but just an ordinary macro. Hard to tell because your questions are IMHO rather vague and hard to answer. If you really want to develop you own LaTeX code that does animations in 3d, the very first step would be to learn to write MWEs, and then to ask questions that are right to the point. Otherwise you and other users on this site may just waste their time.

Comment: Your answer was as helpful as always Schrodinger. Thank you very much!!!